# SQL retrieve and perform arithmetic on values from associated table

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have two tables, as shown below, I'm trying to get a participant's time (finish_time - start_time) in one sql query. Note that start time and finish time need to be retrieved from the occurred_at column of an associated table called race_events.

```
PARTICIPANTS
  id  | membership_id | race_id 
------+---------------+---------
 1133 |           547 |     690
 1121 |           342 |     690


RACE_EVENTS
  id  | participant_id | event_type |  occurred_at  
------+----------------+------------+---------------
 1075 |           1121 | start      | 1366249860579
 1077 |           1121 | finish     | 1366249968936
 1104 |           1133 | start      | 1366250760128
 1107 |           1133 | finish     | 1366250876237
```

I couldn't figure out how to achieve this using joins so I tackled the problem using subqueries like so:

```
SELECT 
(select occurred_at from race_events where participant_id = participants.id and event_type = 'start') as started_at,
(select occurred_at from race_events where participant_id = participants.id and event_type = 'finish') as finished_at, 
participants.* FROM "participants"
```

This got me most of the way there yeilding a result containing the start and finish times for each participant:

```
  started_at   |  finished_at  |  id  | membership_id | race_id 
---------------+---------------+------+---------------+---------
 1366250760128 | 1366250876237 | 1133 |           547 |     690
 1366249860579 | 1366249968936 | 1121 |           342 |     690
```

Ideally though I'd like to also calculate the race_time (finished_at - started_at) in this query too, so the result would look like above but with an additional column called race_time containing the result of (finished_at - started_at) for that row. Can anyone suggest how I might do that?

On a related note, I'm not convinced that the general approach of using subqueries to get the associated values is cleanest or most efficient and I'd really appreciate other suggestions.

I'm using PostgreSQL but I suspect the answer would be the same for any SQL database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you handle races this way? Start and finish should be in the same record. Just update it at the finish.

Comment: I know what you mean. In our case Start and Finish aren't the only race events we have to handle, different types of races have different types of events such as changeovers and splits. We're not too sure what all the types of events will be required in future, that's why I did it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one but be adviced that I've not tried it and it may have some syntax errors but you should get the point

```
SELECT 
    re1.occured_at as started_at, 
    re2.occured_at as finished_at,
    (re2.occured_at - re1.occured_at) as race_time,
    p.id,
    p.membership_id,
    p.race_id

participant_id FROM PARTICIPANTS p 
INNER JOIN RACE_EVENTS re1 ON re1.participant_id = p.id AND re1.event_type = 'start'
INNER JOIN RACE_EVENTS re2 ON re2.participant_id = p.id AND re2.event_type = 'finish'
```

Comment: Thanks so much Dan and mcl. This is a much better approach and works perfectly. Both your answers are essentially the same, wish I could mark both as correct. I didn't know joins could be named like this, learnt something new. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join to race_events twice

```
select somefields, finished.occurred_at - started.occurred_at duration
from participants p join race_events started on p.race_id = started.race_id
and event_type = 'start'
join race_events finished on p.race_id = started.race_id
and event_type = 'finish'
where whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    started_at, finished_at,
    finished_at - started_at race_time,
    p.id, p.membership_id, p.race_id
from
    participants p
    inner join
    race_events res on p.id = res.participant_id
    inner join
    race_events ref on p.id = ref.participant_id
where
    res.event_type = 'start'
    and ref.event_type = 'finish'
```

I think your model is not good and you are missing both a race table and the column race_id in the race_events table.

Comment: Thanks. I simplified that data structure for the sake of the example so there are some bits missing.